# How To Untangle Headphones

Tags: headphones

I am usually a little lazy and forget to prepare my headphones correctly as said in this [question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/195/how-do-i-stop-my-earphones-from-getting-tangled).

My tangled headphones look a bit like this:

[image]

It can take forever to get the headphones reorganized, having to take that wire and put it there and all sorts of complicated things to come.

My question is that is there a hack for easily untangling headphones?

Comment: dunno, other than just picking apart the tangle, not sure what else you can do, really.

Comment: The only thing you can do is prevent them getting tangled in the first part. Can do that by simply wrapping them around something.

Answer (score 3):

I  get this quite a lot and more often than not I can untangle them with a fair amount of success.

Initially, I grab a random wire among the tangled mess and shake it up and down a few times by this strand of wire, this usually removes the worst of the mess and the rest can easily be picked apart as it normally ends up with just one end of them being a little bit tangled.

If you use something like a pen or pencil to pick it apart - it'll have less grip than it does on your fingers so will work out a little bit easier but it all depends on your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it far less tangle-prone by making the wires thicker and stiffer.

Take some soft clear tubing (typically vinyl) and slit it with a razor or x-acto knife, then press the wire into the slit.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this for quite sometime now as a hack and it has worked seamlessly. The best part is that it doesn't require any special effort and is super easy to wind and unwind, both.

[image]

Comment: This will be good for keeping them *from tangling* though my question is how to *untangle them*