# Stop headphone cord from tangling

Tags: headphones, work

I have a pair of headphones with a long cord (2.5m / 8.2 ft) that I use at my desk. It's nice having a long cord -- I can move around at my desk and reach things -- but when I put them down they tend to get tangled around things, especially the arms of my chair. Any advice?

This is unlike the [question about earbuds](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/195/4259) because I don't want to tie them short. (I was asked to edit to show how this was different from this question; you can see my answer just before this parenthetical.)

Comment: bluetooth headphones | better headphones with non-tangle cord

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a **binder clip and a specific roll up style**:

[image]

Every office has these in abundance.  You can easily roll up the ear bud cord using a figure 8 motion using two fingers (index and middle).  Once the 8 feet of cord has been collected, use the binder clip to keep it all together.  The clip can then be attached to your cubical wall with a push pin to keep it off your desk (if you have a cubical).

Comment: I do this for my ear bud cord, but I make sure the cord is within the "triangular tube", and isn't pinched between the pinching edges of the binder clip.  @FlatBanana, do you know if it hurts your cord to pinch it, like you would pinch papers?

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial made rolling devices that allow you to pull out the length of lead you need, which will pull back in when you do not use it.

While you might be able to make one yourself, I do not think it is possible for me to explain it.

You could make a subsitute by connecting your lead to an elastic band which stretches to the longest length you need it but which retracts to as short as you can get it to be.
I would crochet around both elastic and lead, with the elastic stretched to its limit. Sewing or regular connections with tape or clips might work.

But I fear that this method will leave you lacking.